# Assert that optional properties in interface are not null in class at compile time

Tags: typescript, interface, optional-parameters

In Javascript I like to pass an `options object` to a `constructor`, and fill in any missing properties I expected with default values:

```
function foo(options) {
   if(options.a == undefined) {
      options.a = 1;
   }
   if(options.b == undefined) {
      options.b = 'hello';
   }
   this.options = options;
}

new foo({a: 10});
```

Trying to implement this pattern in Typescript, I have:

```
interface Options {
    a?: number;
    b?: string;
}

class Foo {
   options: Options;
   constructor(options: Options) {
      if(options.a == undefined) {
         options.a = 1;
      }
      if(options.b == undefined) {
         options.b = 'hello';
      }
      this.options = options;
   }
}
```

When I use `options` in the `class` later, I know that all the properties are defined. However, Typescript isn't aware of this, so this statement produces an error:

```
let a:Number = this.options.a; // Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type number.
```

Additionally, I don't want to allow code in the `class` to assign a `null` or `undefined` value to the property later:

```
this.options.a = undefined; // should produce compiler error
```

**Is there a way to define my types, so the properties of `Options` aren't nullable when used in the `class` *without defining two `Options` interfaces*?**

For example, I know I could make another `interface` for internal use:

```
interface OptionsSafe {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}

// in Foo constructor
this.options = {
    a: a != undefined ? options.a! : 1,
    b: b != undefined ? options.b! : 'hello'
};
```

But then I need to define the properties of options in two separate interfaces and make sure they're always in sync (this solution would be great if Typescript can generate both interfaces from one definition).

I also don't want to pass all the properties as individual, optional arguments, because

1. there can be dozens or more options and
2. the function arguments could drift from the `Options` interface, so I still have to keep two "interfaces" in sync.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to used the built-in `Partial` type that Typescript provides. This may be too close to "defining two `Options` interfaces" for you, but I'll show you what I mean anyways.

Typescript provides a built-in type `Partial` that is defined as `type Partial<T> = {[P in keyof T]?: T[P]}`.

What this means you could do is only define the `Options` interface with all of the members, but use the partial version of it for your constructor. Like this:

```
interface Options {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}

class Foo {
   options: Options;
   constructor(options: Partial<Options>) {
      const defaultOptions = {
          a: 1,
          b: 'hello'
      };

      this.options = Object.assign(defaultOptions, options);
   }
}
```

In order for Typescript to correctly infer that you've got all the necessary properties on the object, you will need to move away from the `if` statement logic you were using to something more like the above.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Didn't know about mapped types, very useful

Comment: I've discovered one drawback of using `Object.assign` in this context--it copies all "enumerable own" properties, including those with null and undefined values. To protect against null/undefined, I need to iterate over the properties and delete unwanted values from the object.